# how to include dependency classes to war project's WEB-INF/classes folder in maven

Tags: maven

I've a project B which has a dependency on project A. Both project's packaging is jar. Another project C packaging is war. Project C contains no java classes. It contains only webapps folder. Project C has dependency on project B. I want the war to be packaged in just a way that all the java classes from Project A and B should be copied to WEB-INF/classes folder. How can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [unpack](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html) goal of [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html) in your pom to unpack the desired dependencies to a folder and ensure maven war plugin [includes this folder](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html).